# Output singular boolean htm tag attribute values in Ember.View attributeBindings

Tags: html, ember.js

The Ember docs for Ember.View attributeBindings states that:
http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html

> If the return value of an attributeBindings monitored property is a boolean the property will follow HTML's pattern of repeating the attribute's name as its value

However, I am marking my pages up with schema.org semantic data and would like to set the itemscope attribute on one of my div tags. But when I do this with attributeBindings Ember wants to give me:

> itemscope="itemscope"

rather than just a vanilla "itemscope" boolean attribute tag.

I think the answer to this may well be "not currently possible" but it seems like something that *must* be doable so I wanted to appeal to the wisdom of S.O. before giving up.

Answer (score 0):

If you set itemscope to the String `'true'` rather than the boolean `true` then it should work.